# MySQL: use value from another table as column alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

We have this one table that is really funky and I'm trying to get a descriptive result set out of it.
This table stores a tightly-related yet disparate collection of data types, and the meaningful column "names" are stored in a separate table. I think it'll be easier to show than to explain.

**A Simplified and Abstract Example:**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `something_obscure` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `obscure_type_id` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
      `segment1` varchar(92) DEFAULT NULL,
      `segment2` varchar(92) DEFAULT NULL,
      `segment3` varchar(92) DEFAULT NULL,
      `datetime_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
    INSERT INTO `something_obscure` 
      (`id`, `obscure_type_id`, `segment1`, `segment2`, `segment3`, `datetime_created`) 
    VALUES
      ('250', 1, '123', '456', '789', '2013-05-14 10:13:44'),
      ('251', 2, 'abc', 'def', 'ghk', NULL),
      ('252', 2, NULL, NULL, 'mnop', NULL);


 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `obscure_type` (
      `id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `description` varchar(92) DEFAULT NULL,
      `segment1` varchar(92) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'a LABEL/NAME for the data found in Segment1 of the Obscure table',
      `segment2` varchar(92) DEFAULT NULL,
      `segment3` varchar(92) DEFAULT NULL,
      `datetime_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
    INSERT INTO `obscure_type` 
      (`id`, `type`, `description`, `segment1`, `segment2`, `segment3`) 
    VALUES
      (1, 'native', 'a descriptive description', 'best', 'worst', 'other'),
      (2, 'alien', 'another descriptive desc', 'in', 'out', 'stationary');
```

Initially, I was expecting to have put meaningful names to the columns in the business logic (in php), but if I could just get SQL to handle that before our program even *sees* this result set, that'd be ***awesome*!**

**GOAL:**
Just to illustrate (I know this won't actually work), I was thinking something kinda like:

```
SELECT 
  data.segment1 AS type.segment1,
  data.segment2 AS type.segment2,
  data.segment3 AS type.segment3
FROM something_obscure AS data
JOIN pobscure_type AS type
ON data.obscure_type_id = type.id
WHERE data.obscure_type_id = 2
```

And that would return:

```
----------------------------
| in   | out  | stationary |
----------------------------
| abc  | def  | ghk        |
| NULL | NULL | mnop       |
----------------------------
```

**SUMMARY:**
How would one go about setting aliases to the ***values*** of another table?
We do not want to specify the alias name, we want the alias name set by the value of the referenced field. Is that possible?

Comment: If querying for `obscure_type_id=1` the alias for `segment1` would be "best", and if querying for `obscure_type_id=2`, then the alias would be "in" ... seems like it would implode, though, if a query were ever run for more than one type id ... regardless, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to wrap aliases into backqoutes?

```
SELECT 
  data.segment1 AS `type.segment1`,
  data.segment2 AS `type.segment2`,
  data.segment3 AS `type.segment3`
FROM something_obscure AS data
JOIN obscure_type AS type
ON data.obscure_type_id = type.id
```

Comment: I think I might have been a little unclear. I'll add a comment to my post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes around the  aliases

```
SELECT 
  data.segment1 AS 'segment1',
  data.segment2 AS'segment2',
  data.segment3 AS 'segment3'
FROM something_obscure AS data
JOIN obscure_type AS type
ON data.obscure_type_id = type.id
```

<kbd>[**Working fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09a69/3)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Other demo with type.***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09a69/5)</kbd>

Comment: You should use \`back-ticks\`, not single-quotes.

Comment: @dar7yl i was writing the bacticks but i saw other answer posted using backticks so i changed my answer:)